# Recent Achievements shows incorrect value

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, achievements-dialog

I noticed this a couple of times before asking this question. The "Recent Achievements" notification button is showing incorrect value. Here is a screenshot:
[image: screenshot for inconsistant values]

Comment: The green number is how much reputation you have gained since the last time you opened the achievment dialogue, so the -2 might come from a previous day.

Comment: @Magisch Correct, As you can see in the image, last reputation gain was +10 but the number shown is +8. My last time visit to the "Reputation" tab would not be less that +10!

Comment: Any other sites beyond SO you might have incurred a down vote? Or a suggested edit on a now deleted post? See also: https://stackoverflow.com/reputation

Comment: if I had to guess @Prashant I would say a post you have edited got deleted since your last visit to the achievment box, triggering a -2 reputation event because you lost the rep from the approved edit there, which is what makes it show +8 only.

Comment: @rene No, SO is the site where I am mostly active

Comment: @Magisch Your explanation makes sense. Let me check.

Comment: @Magisch As it turns out to be, one of the posts that I edited was deleted. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The green number above the achievment box shows the net change to your reputation since the last time you opened the achievment box, if it is positive.

In addition to that, some negative reputation events do not show up in the achievment box, but count towards this number anyways.

For instance, as happened in this case, if a post that you have edited while below the reputation threshold to edit without review gets deleted, you lose the +2 reputation gained from the edit. This is not shown directly, but does count towards what constitutes the green number.